# Ending task in task manager works, but taskkill in cmd does not. Why?

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to terminate a software every time it is done transcoding a movie file. To automate this I made a small batch script. Therein I tried to use taskkill like this:

```
taskkill /im taskname.exe /t /f
```

But I always get the following error message: 
ERROR: The process with PID 6708 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

I also tried to start the cmd window as administrator and I also tried PowerShell. But when I do tasklist afterwards, it still shows the task.

Funny thing is that the task gets instantly terminated when I right-click on it in the task manager and end task. Which command does the "end task" call in the task manager? Something I can use to automate in a batch file?

Comment: I don't know, but does tasklist list it?  tasklist >file.

Comment: Yes tasklist shows it.

Comment: and I guess other programs close fine. Have you considered 3rd party command line  apps? eg maybe `nircmd.exe closeprocess theprocess.exe`

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! nircmd did the job. Thanks a lot! If you want you can post this as the answer: `nircmd.exe killprocess processname`

Comment: Yes, tried admin prompt and PowerShell admin prompt. I think this is a bug of the software I was trying to close, not something Windows did wrong. It is the command line version of easyDCP JPEG 2000 Standalone Transcoder. And it does not close itself after transcoding movies that come from ffmpeg.

Comment: @Karan read his question, he wrote "I also tried to start the cmd window as administrator"

Comment: @barlop: So he did. Do you have any idea how nircmd killprocess terminates the misbehaving process in a way taskkill can't?

Comment: @Karan I don't know, but there is a program that lets you spy on api calls.. called API monitor by rohitab http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor   I recall once using that or something similar long ago to see what API function a program was using to do something. And that or something like it might help point to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [barlop](https://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop) the third party command line app nircmd.exe did the job!

```
nircmd.exe killprocess processname
```

Comment: Mark this as your answer then.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I don't remember having that restriction.

Comment: Yeah, maybe this restriction will go away once I have posted more on superuser.

Comment: I doubt the restriction ever goes away 'cos i'm currently on > 9000 rep and still have that restriction! @paradroid maybe you also have the restriction but just haven't tried answering your own question much

Comment: @barlop Possibly; but it is possible to answer your own question at the same time as posting the question.

Comment: @paradroid I don't know what you are trying to tell me, but i'm telling you that I've always had the same experience as schmiddl, which is that if I post a question, and post an answer, then I have to wait two days before it lets me accept my own answer. And yeah you can post the answer straight after posting the question, nobody is denying that, but both schmiddl and I have found that to actually accept your own answer, you have to wait two days.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot kill it by name, but have Process ID, you can try to kill it by PID:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('WMIC process where "Name='process.exe'" get ProcessId /value') do set pid=%%i 
echo Going to kill PID: %pid%
taskkill.exe /PID %pid%
```

Comment: Accessing the process by name or pid does not change anything. The error remains with taskkill.

Comment: What is the name of software You're trying to kill

Comment: Command line version of easyDCP JPEG 2000 Standalone Transcoder 1.0. It does not close itself after transcoding movies made with ffmpeg.

Comment: Checked their cmd manuals - not much there. As I know such kind of problem is common when executable is relaunched by some module. Why do you need to kill it, if software is designed to be persistent in memory.

Comment: Yes, there is a separate modul for the command line version. I spoke at length with their support and it was not supposed to be persistent. There is even a flag in the CLI version to turn persistence off. I have automated a few things with batch files. For the batch to continue, the software needs to be closed. But even with persistence off, it does not close sometimes. The Standalone Transcoder comes packaged with the easyDCP Creator+. They offer a trial version. But I don't think they offer a trial for my older version anymore.

Comment: If there is a flag for persistence and it is not working - this is a bug! If You payed for this software I think You can ask for free update of this executable.

Comment: Thats what I did :). They fixed the bug in the new version, but introduced a new one, which is related to the old one. I gave them some sample material and they will fix the new bug in 2-3 months in the next release. But in the meantime I have to keep working. Thats why I needed a workaround for the old version. Thanks for your help!